# The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2. what to do

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

[image]

i am making ML project on covid 19 dataset and getting error like this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(covid, covid['Death Ratio']):
    strat_train_set = covid.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = covid.loc[test_index]
```

i tried to a lot to solve but i was not able to do so

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-42056912ab46> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
      2 split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
----> 3 for train_index, test_index in split.split(covid, covid['Death Ratio']):
      4     strat_train_set = covid.loc[train_index]
      5     strat_test_set = covid.loc[test_index]

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
   1385         """
   1386         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
-> 1387         for train, test in self._iter_indices(X, y, groups):
   1388             yield train, test
   1389 

c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in _iter_indices(self, X, y, groups)
   1713         class_counts = np.bincount(y_indices)
   1714         if np.min(class_counts) < 2:
-> 1715             raise ValueError("The least populated class in y has only 1"
   1716                              " member, which is too few. The minimum"
   1717                              " number of groups for any class cannot"

ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

[image: THIS IS ERROR]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This problem seems to be related with your data. It says that in your `covid['Death Ratio']` column there is one class that only appears one time (the algorithm can't handle with only one). Can you edit your answer and show the uniques values of this column, and how many times they appear?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot perform a stratified split using `covid['Death Ratio']` as there is some value in this column that is represented less than 1 time.

If you want to stratify the split based on this column, you could discretize it. Otherwise, you could stratify your split based on another value. In my point of view, I would not perform a stratify split based on this column but rather a simple `ShuffleSplit`.

**EDIT**:

If you want to perform multiple split, use (e.g: 5) use:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
splits = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

If you want to perform a single split you can use:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```